# react-router Redirect vs history.push

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-redux, react-router-dom

I was reading [react-router-redux examples](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux/examples) and I confused,
what is the difference beetween:

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

...

<Redirect to='/login' />
```

and

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'

...

push('/login')
```

Comment: See https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect : A simple redirect will add an entry to the history stack (you can go back to the previous route); if `push` with `false`, then the current url route is overritten, and you can't use the back button to return to the state you just left.

Comment: @Piran, not true. `Redirect` overrides the current history unless you specify the push prop (as per the link you supplied)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

**Redirect**

Rendering a `<Redirect>` will navigate to a new location. The new location will `override the current location in the history stack,` like server-side redirects (HTTP 3xx) do.

whereas **History**

**push function** `Pushes a new entry onto the history stack`

Comment: Any benefits of overwriting the current history stack ?

Comment: @DollarAkshay, the user is not blocked when trying to navigate back.

Comment: A use case: A user tried to access their settings page, but is not logged in. By using `Redirect`, we can redirect them to the log in page and remove the "settings" from their history, so that their back button won't take them back there.

Bonus: It's nice to remember where they were trying to go, so after they log in we can redirect them there; in this case, to their settings page.

Comment: On more recent versions of react router, you'll need to use `<Navigate replace />` to emulate the above `Redirect` behaviour

Answer (score 37):

The `<Redirect>` component will, by default, replace the current location with a new location in the history stack, basically working as a server-side redirect.

But it can also be used with the property `push` and in this case it will push a new entry into the history stack, working the same way as `history.push`.

In fact the `<Redirect>` component uses the history `push` and `replace` methods behinds the scene. It is just a more React way of navigating.

So basically you have two ways of navigating:

1. Use the `history.push` and `history.replace` in a component (usually wrapped with the `withRouter` HOC, so that you can have access to the `location` object without having to pass it from parent to child.
2. Use the `<Redirect>` component with or without the `push` property, depending

Answer (score 3):

I noticed a difference between the two in my use case with Redux and Typescript.

Here's a simplified version of it:

```js
export const LandingPage = () => {
  const { history } = useHistory();
    const { viewer } = useSelector(state => state.viewer);

    // Redirect method returns another component that handles the redirect
    // without mounting any of the route components
    if (!viewer?.token) {
        return <Redirect to="/signin" />;
    }

    // History.push method mounts the route component and runs 'onload' functions
    // Which can still throw an error if there's no viewer 
    // if (!viewer?.token) {
    //  history.push('/signin');
    //    // return history.push('/signin');  // throws Typescript error
    // }

    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
            <Route path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
            <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
        </Switch>
    );
};
```

When using history.push() method, the JSX in your return statement can still mount and run, whereas returning Redirect can block the rest of your code.