# How can I redirect via react router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Based on the `isLoggedIn` I need to route to different components.

I'm getting the login page but not able to render homepage.

```
{this.state.isLoggedIn ?
    (
      <Route
        path='/home'
        render={() => <HomePage  onLogout={this.onLogout} />}
      />
    )
    :
    (
      <Route exact path='/' component={() => <LoginPage onLogin={this.onLogin} />}/>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect by rendering a `<Redirect>` will navigate to a new location. The new location will override the current location in the history stack, like server-side redirects (HTTP 3xx) do.

```
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router'

<Route exact path="/" render={() => (
  loggedIn ? (
    <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>
  ) : (
    <PublicHomePage/>
  )
)}/>
```

For pass prop by redirect

```
<Redirect to={{
    pathname: '/dashboard',
    state: { id: '123' }
}} />
```

Then you can access prop via `this.props.location.state.id`

Comment: how can i send the props to the components in this redirect

Comment: let me add more example in answer. @ReNinja I added example for passing props by redirect. please check

Comment: where can I specify the component name Homepage
<HomePage  onLogout={this.onLogout} />

Comment: I think you can check this tutorial https://blog.pshrmn.com/entry/simple-react-router-v4-tutorial/
have
  return (
    <main>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
        <Route path='/roster' component={Roster}/>
        <Route path='/schedule' component={Schedule}/>
      </Switch>
    </main>
  );
so you can declare component for route, and redirect to that route

Comment: Getting parsing error in the redirect
`Line 36:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  34 |     <Redirect to={{
  35 |     pathname: '/home',
> 36 |     onLogout:{this.onLogout}
     |               ^
  37 | }}/>
  38 |   ) : (
  39 |    <LoginPage onLogin={this.onLogin} />`

Comment: I have tried the below code but the homepage is not rendering
` {this.state.isLoggedIn ?
          (<div>
            <Route
                    path='/home'
                    render={props=> <HomePage  onLogout={this.onLogout} />}
                  />
           </div>
          )
          :
         ( <Route
                   exact path='/'
                   render={props => <LoginPage className="login-page"  onLogin={this.onLogin} />}
                 />)
         
        }`

Answer (score 1):

Use [Redirect](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect)

From your parent component, pass `this.state.isLoggedIn` as props to LoginPage and HomePage component.

in LoginPage component

```
render(){
  if(this.props.isLoggedIn){
   return <Redirect to='/home' />
  }

  return ( your login page )
}
```

Do the same in your HomePage component with the Redirect's path `'/'`instead.

Comment: Is it ok to redirect in the render() function ? And what is the difference between  "<Redirect to='/home' />" and "this.props.history.push('/home');"

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yeah, it is fine to redirect in render because <Redirect /> is a react's component. The differences between those two are here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54452810/10104154

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.props.history.push(myRoutes)` and send route in the argument. It will redirect you to desired route.